# Was United Fruit Company connected to the Rockefeller family?

Tags: united-states, latin-america

Was United Fruit Company connected to or controlled by the Rockefeller family?

[Wikipedia says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Fruit_Company)

> The directors of United Fruit Company (UFCO) had lobbied to convince the Truman and Eisenhower administrations that Colonel Árbenz intended to align Guatemala with the Eastern Bloc .. the relationship between the Eisenhower administration and UFCO demonstrated the influence of corporate interest on U.S. foreign policy. United States Secretary of State John Foster Dulles, an avowed opponent of communism, was also a member of the law firm, Sullivan and Cromwell, which had represented United Fruit. His brother Allen Dulles, director of the CIA, was also a board member of United Fruit. United Fruit Company is the only company known to have a CIA cryptonym.

There are plenty of sources that show the huge influence of United Fruit Company.

But the movie ["The Power Principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_Principle) mentions that Rockefeller controlled the company (I guess as a major shareholder):

> *[16:42]:* Especially concerned were shareholders of Rockefeller's United Fruit Company.

Is that true?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132440/discussion-on-question-by-joe-jobs-was-united-fruit-company-connected-to-the-roc).